# How to exclude menu items on collapse in bootstrap nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

How do I exclude menu items from my nav when collapse takes place?

To be more explicit, I have some list items as such:

```
<li>|</li>
```

Used as a spacer between other menu items. The pipes inside of the "li" tags are showing as items in the collapsed nav menu, and I want to ignore these on collapse.

Is there a property available that I can add to the element to make bootstrap completely ignore adding my "spacers" to the nav list of menu items?

Comment: What about you apply a css rule to your list items instead: Like  `ul li:not(:first-child) {border: 1px solid #000;}` so you do not have extra DOM elements just to style your menu .. And if you do not want them in collapsed state, make use of the applied bootstrap classes of the collapsing element **"collapse" / "collapse in"** in your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, refer here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes for the available classes.

For your example, you would use something like this:

`<li class="hidden-xs">|</li>`

Comment: Wow. Thank you for this response. Works perfectly. The nav divider lines that I'm using disappear when shrinking screen.